# Jenkins slave run as a different user

Tags: svn, jenkins

I am writing a Jenkins job which would get the patch as an input from the user and do a build, sanity tests and then commits in behalf of the developer if the build and test passes.We use Subversion as our source code control system. When 'svn commit' is triggered  by a developer, subversion doesn't prompt for a password and reads it from the user's home dir.

The slaves run as a common user (which has passwordless sudo on  these machines) on a dedicated set of machines. Now my question is can I have the slaves run the job as a different user ( developer who submits his patch) so that when it comes to the commit part, the commit happens automatically in the developers name without prompting for a password.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: also looking for this. Did you manage to do it?

Comment: we are currently using jenkins code as pipeline and it allows us to use stages, where we can assign a node for each stage. for the  stage which needs a different user, configure the stage accordingly.